# Google Developers - Email Audit Api - Error Code 1301 -> EntityDoesNotExist

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I had a working api request code for mail box dump request for a long while. But suddenly the api started to return the error below. Did I missed some news about apis on google? Can any one guide me through this?

Thank you for your attention and help!

[image]

Comment: Try posting this in the issue tracker, according to an [early post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-manager/cd_4No_YG1I) it is a bug, but since the last update of the post was 2011 this issue might resurfaced.

Comment: Here's the current issue in the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68252218